# How to do a sorting in VBA?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have a table with header and data in columns from A to D with changing row number (number of rows is more than 66800). I'd like to sort data from Z to A order by column C.

There are a lot of different solutions in VBA on internet, but none worked correctly for me.

My code gives me an error:

```
    Sub SortDescending()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
lRow = Sheets("atm_hh").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Sheets("atm_hh").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  With Sheets("atm_hh")
    .Select
    .Range("A2:" & Cells(lRow, lCol).Address).Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), _
                                              Order1:=xlDescending, _
                                              Header:=xlGuess, _
                                              OrderCustom:=1, _
                                              MatchCase:=False, _
                                              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I meant not a VBA error, but in excel C column is sorted wrong. For example 9,99 is upper than 33,45 etc.

Comment: maybe excel doesn't recognize the commas in your locale and you need to use dots as the thousands separator?

Comment: Be sure that all of the values in Column C are set to numeric type and that Excel is configured to treat comma as decimal point. That way the sort will work correctly.

Comment: @Goosebumbs yes, i need to sort just by column C, so all the other cells must correspond

Comment: @vba4all no no, i checked, with point it does not work

Comment: but in the `sheets.range` you sort on `A2:D66800` (for example). should that not be `C2:C66800` ?

Comment: @MikeMeinz i've put a column C in numeric format, but still it sorts in a wrong way

Comment: Perhaps one or more cells contain a space character.  That would prevent Excel from recognizing the value as numeric even though you set the type to numeric.

Comment: @Goosebumbs it seems if i put C2 instead of A2 it sorts just C column, but all the other columns remain freezed

Comment: that is strange.. is it a table or just a list of items?

Comment: @Goosebumbs it does not have borders, so probably a list of items

Comment: make it a table then.. you can't sort it if the rows are not linked to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Sub SortDescending()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("atm_hh")

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    lRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In sh.Range("C2:C" & lRow)
        cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, ",", ".")
    Next

    Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.0"

    sh.Cells.AutoFilter
    sh.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sh.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C" & lRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sh.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, but with Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "0" it puts 0.55 as 55. Should i use Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.0"?

Comment: If you want the zeros in front yeah

Comment: well 55 is not the same as 0.55, i need to keep data in a correct way, cause then i need to sum them, i need to have it even in 0.00 format. Is it ok, i mean will not it change a value?

Comment: I couldn't tell without testing on the actual values. Can you not test yourself and compare the old ones with the new ones?